# Get underlying socket from HttpClient

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I am using `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` to make HTTP requests. For troubleshooting purposes, I would like to know the remote IP address of the underlying socket that is used to make the HTTP request.

Is there a clean way to get this information?

My first target is .NET Framework 4.7.2, and after that I will have my sight on .NET Core 3.1 and .NET 6.

Comment: You might have to use `SocketsHttpHandler`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.socketshttphandler.connectcallback?view=net-6.0

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama Like I said, my first target is .NET Framework 4.72. `SocketsHttpHandler` is not available in .NET Framework as far as I can tell.

Comment: Oh, for some reason I thought it was. It looks like you're right though. Short of creating your own `HttpMessageHandler` implementation, I'm out of ideas.